# Java Template invocation - runtime deduction

Tags: java, generics

I was learning Java templates. As generics are compiled, I was hoping runtime deduction of type and hence invocation accordingly.

Seems it doesn't. i.e. deduction is based on compile time type deduction, although template itself is compiled.

Test Interface:

```
interface op {
    public Object Do(Object o);
    public Class getClass1();
    public Object getTest();
}
```

Interface implementation

```
class intop implements op{
    public Object Do(Object o) {
        return (Integer) o;
    }

    public Class getClass1() {
        return Integer.class;
    }
    public Object getTest() {
        return new Integer(1);
    }
}
class strop implements op{
    public Object Do(Object o) {
        return (String) o;
    }

    public Class getClass1() {
        return String.class;
    }

    public Object getTest() {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Template & Specilizations

```
class Utils {
    public static void performOp(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Interger Object :" + i);
    }

    public static void performOp(String s) {
        System.out.println("String object : " + s);
    }

    public static <T> void performOp(T o) {
        System.out.println("Generic Object :" + o.toString());
    }
}
```

Testing

```
public class GenMethod {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Utils.performOp(1);
        Utils.performOp("Test");
        Utils u = new Utils();
        Integer i = 4;
        Object o = i;
        ArrayList<op> a = new ArrayList<op>();
        a.add(new intop());
        a.add(new strop());

        Random rn = new Random();
        op b = a.get(rn.nextInt(2));

        Utils.performOp(b.getClass1().cast(b.getTest()));
        Utils.performOp(u);
    }
}
```

I was Expecting output to be something like:

```
Interger Object :1
String object : Test
Interger Object :1
Generic Object :Utils@64c3c749
```

But It was :

```
Interger Object :1
String object : Test
Generic Object :1
Generic Object :Utils@3ce53108
```

Is there a way to correctly do specialized template method invocation based on runtime type deduction?

PS : I want to avoid the 'instanceof' & 'if..else' ladders as much as possible.

Comment: Java generics are not templates, there are no templates in Java. Btw why not putting `performOp` into `op` interface instead of creating static utility methods?

Comment: Generics loose the type information during compilation. I would use strategy pattern with a Map<Class<?>,Strategy>

Comment: @macias yes, that is one of my options.

Comment: @TagirValeev Yes, that is good to solve this specific problem. Bu I wish to reuse the 'op's for various other functionalities, which are to be added later.